# Is there one word for "not challenged enough"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage, synonyms, diction

I was typing an essay and wrote unchallenged to mean that the subject didn't feel challenged, but then I realized that unchallenged means "undisputed" and the definition that I thought isn't really attributed to the word. So, my question is, is there one adjective that means "not challenged enough?" 
Thank you :)

Comment: I occasionally come across "underchallenged", but this is not a word that is in wide-spread use or recorded in standard dictionaries.

Comment: **Underutilized** might work, depending on the *exact* meaning you have in mind.

Comment: @JasonBassford, that's a good alternative, but it doesn't fit the connotation and makes the subject sound more like a tool than an employee. It's essentially supposed to say "I feel like an (adj) employee"

Comment: @njuffa, Yeah, it doesn't sound right when I try to put in "underchallenged"

Comment: @ManaalSiddiqui That is presumably because you have not come across this word before. In the few instances where I encountered "underchallenged", its meaning (based on context) was clearly "not challenged enough". See also [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/underchallenge)

Comment: @njuffa Still, I feel like I should weigh other options. Do you know any?

Comment: You need to provide more objective criteria. For instance, *I* don't feel that calling myself *underutilized* means that I'm referring to myself more as a tool than an employee. I've heard the term used for people many times.

Comment: First, can you see that your having used "unchallenged" then realising unchallenged means "undisputed" broadly means only that the definition you attributed to the word doesn't work?

Failing your answer no; there is not one adjective that means "not challenged enough"

Answer (score 1):

The term I have heard and used myself is: Underemployed.

Comment: Underemployed is often used to mean that a person has a job, but it doesn't meet their financial needs.  So the person isn't unemployed, but isn't fully employed.  It's different from a person whose work doesn't meet their needs for fulfillment or stimulation or significance.

Comment: @jejorda2 I've more often heard underemployed used to mean that a person is qualified for a more challenging or higher-paying job, but has taken a less demanding (or rewarding) job. Example: having a  law degree, but running a hot dog stand.

Comment: Collins indicates that my definition is American and yours is British: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/underemployed